# delete posts forms with laravel

Tags: jquery, forms, laravel, rest

I have a problem with deleting posts by laravel forms by delete method with jquery.

My forms code in Blade template looks:

```
     @foreach ($posts as $post)
                <tr> 
                    <th scope="row"></th>
                    <td>{{ $post->topic }}</td> 
                    <td>{{ $post->created_at }}</td> 
                    <td>
                    <a href = "{{ url('dashboard/edit/'.$post->id) }}" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a>
                    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['deletePost', $post->id], 'class' => 'deleteForm']) !!}

                            {!! Form::submit('Delete Post',['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}

                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                    </td> 

                </tr> 
@endforeach
```

My jquery Code:

```
 (function($) {

    $('.deleteForm').submit(function(event){



            event.preventDefault();
            alert('delete post');
            //$("#deletePostModal").modal("show");
    });
    $("#deletePostConfirm").click(function(){

            var token = $(this).data('token');
            console.log(token);
            /*
            $.ajax({
                    url:route,
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {_method: 'delete', _token :token},
                    success:function(msg){

                    });

            })*/
        });
})(jQuery);
```

Output HTML:

```
      <tr> 
                <th scope="row"></th>
                <td>Odkrycie gwiazdy z ezgoplanetą</td> 
                <td>2017-04-16 17:38:59</td> 
                <td>
                <a href = "http://localhost:8000/dashboard/edit/9" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a>
                <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/dashboard/delete/9" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="deleteForm"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="R8TueiGXm2u60YqnPTMtxGTEcsRUiIf7giwVqu4p">

                        <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete Post">

                </form>
</tr>
```

Function submit dosen't react. I don't know why. Everything look fine.

Could someone help me with my problem? I would be very grateful, greetings.

Comment: Please show us how have you defined your route

Comment: Route::delete('dashboard/delete/{id}','adminPanelController@deletePost')->name('deletePost');     - My route. Problem is with jquery, without everythig works fine

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.data` function You can use something simpler than that we will use [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

```
$(".deleteForm").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var inputData = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
                url:route,
                type: 'post',
                data: inputData,
                success:function(msg){

                });

        });
    });
```

Comment: Main problem is with: $('.deleteForm').submit(function(event) - I don't know why it dosen't work. Don't you why?

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? you mean it refreshes the page or what?

Comment: Yes it refreshes page and dosen't call submit method in jquery

Comment: I don't know where did you get `#deletePostConfirm` but i have updated my answer check it and tell me what you get.

Comment: Problem was because I didn't have : $( document ).ready(function() {